# Glassfish - debug JDBC connection pool behavior

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

If I have a JDBC connection pool (datasource) in Glassfish, is there a way I can log debugging info like when it creates a new connection vs. using a pooled one?

In particular I'm trying to troubleshoot the connection validation process, and not sure if that's causing new physical connections to be created.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you define your connection pool? What kind of drivers do you use?

Comment: `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource`, as `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can monitor your application resources through the server console.

Go to `server > Monitor > Resources` and see the stats of your application

Example below:

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for but everything coming back zeros, which can't be right.

Comment: The zeros turned out to be an issue with domain.xml and a bug in Glassfish: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20688