# Can database connection pool count be determined?

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc

Please let me know if connection count be determined dynamically through program?

I wanted to know this as I want to see if my connections are returning back to the pool after my transaction is completed. If there is any other way to determine this, please advise me.

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pooled connections are usually controlled on application server level. Therefore you can see the status of your pool on the server level and not on the application level. (Generally that is the case).

See here on how to [Glassfish - debug JDBC connection pool behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476676/glassfish-debug-jdbc-connection-pool-behavior/17477201#17477201)